# Does "does not achieve x and y" equal "achieve neither x nor y"?

Tags: neither-nor

Consider the following three statements:

1. "If Tenant does not achieve x and y then Tenant may terminate the lease."
2. "If Tenant achieves neither x nor y then Tenant may terminate the lease."
3. "If Tenant fails to achieve both x and y then Tenant may terminate the lease."

The goal is to only allow Tenant to terminate the lease if they fail at x and fail at y.The situation we want to avoid is Tenant succeeding at one but failing at the other, and therefore claiming "I did not achieve x and y, I only achieved x. Therefore, since I did not achieve both x and y, I may terminate the lease."

Sentence #1 is the current wording in the lease. I am arguing that it needs to be changed to sentence #2, as that is the only wording where no counterargument could be made that achieving one or the other is grounds for lease termination. I am not sure if sentence #3 works or not, but it seems less bulletproof than sentence #2 to me.

Which sentence(s), if any, achieve the stated goal?

Comment: For a legal document, you should probably consult a lawyer. As a general guideline, however, in any sort of legal document, ambiguity and opportunity for "misinterpretation" absolutely should be reduced to the lowest possible level.

Comment: If by "achieve" you mean receive some object or benefit, then either of the phrases would allow the tenant to terminate the lease for not achieving either X or Y. I'm confused as to what you intend the clause to mean. If a significant amount of money is at stake, you should consult a lawyer.

Comment: I made my case with the caveat that I would surrender if this was a legal writing issue as opposed to an English grammar issue. Our attorney stated that it was indeed a grammar issue, and that he was reading sentence #1 to mean the same as sentence #3, and that they both seemed to him to achieve the goal of  having the only grounds for termination be the failure to achieve x and also the failure to achieve y.  My argument is that sentence #2 is the only one that achieves our goal without any ambiguity, and disallows an either-or scenario from being grounds for termination.

Comment: Also, to answer your question more directly, in the context of the lease, "If Tenant does not achieve x and y, then Tenant may terminate the lease" means "If Tenant's governing body does not appropriate funding for the lease and the operation of  the entity, then Tenant may terminate the lease." The funding for lease is x and the funding for the operation of the entity is y. In no way are we trying to let them out of their lease if the governing body does not fund one but does fund the other. They only get out if the governing body de-funds both.

Comment: My argument is that the following statement is the only one that achieves our goal without the opportunity for misinterpretation: "If Tenant's governing body appropriates funding for neither the lease nor the operation of the entity, then Tenant may terminate the lease." Am I correct in my argument?

Comment: The first sentence is wrong.  When it is a negative statement, we use "or" rather than "and."  The third isn't wrong on that basis because it is actually a positive statement, meaning it does not employ "not."  To be properly worded, the first sentence must read, "If Tenant does not achieve x or y..."

Comment: This is just an aside and doesn't relate to your question, but you should nonetheless know that a comma is required before "then" in all three of those sentences.  A conditional sentence contains two clauses: the dependent clause expressing the condition, called the protasis, and the main clause expressing the consequence, called the apodosis.  Since the "if" clause is a dependent clause that appears in advance of the "then" main clause, grammar requires a comma appear afterwards.  Only if the dependent "if" clause appears after the "then" main clause is no comma required.

Comment: What country are you in, please, Jordano? It’s not impossible but it is almost inconceivable any British lawyer would use that language in a contract and even less likely that the other party would accept it. For that reason that Question would be hardly more suited to a legal forum than English Language Usage: it’s about logic alone. In all cases, “If Tenant… then Tenant may…” seems backwards. Don't you really mean "If Tenant… then Landlord may…”? By the way most lawyers hate commas, insisting (often rightly) that they lead more to ambiguity than to clarity.

Comment: Sentences 1 and 3 are ambiguous, so I'd use sentence 2.  If you want to avoid "neither ... nor ..." then you could use the longer but unambiguous formulation "if the tenant fails to achieve x and also fails to achieve y, then ...."

Comment: Echoing previous comments, it seems to me that  either "achieve" here is the wrong choice of words, or the "terminate" phrase should be changed. "Failure to achieve" normally implies a penalty: if terminating the lease is indeed a penalty, I would have expected it to be imposed by a different party (e.g. a landlord as indicated previously); if it is a reward, the sentence doesn't make a lot of sense (a reward for failure to achieve is odd).

Answer (score 2):

From a logical perspective, the answer is no. They are not equivalent.

---

> Does not achieve X and Y.

This statement is true if any of the following results occur:

1. Only X is achieved.
2. Only Y is achieved.
3. Neither X nor Y is achieved.

But here is your second statement:

> Achieves neither X nor Y.

This is only true in the *third* result listed above.

If the first or second result occurs, then **does not achieve X and Y** will be *true*—but **achieves neither X nor Y** will be *false*.

Therefore, your two statements are not logically equivalent.

---

For further clarification, in order for the logical **nor** to evaluate to "truth," the conditions on *both* its sides must evaluate to "false."

Or (as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR)):

> In boolean logic, **logical nor** or **joint denial** is a truth-functional operator which produces a result that is the negation of logical or. That is, a sentence of the form (*p* NOR *q*) is true precisely when neither *p* nor *q* is true—i.e. when both of *p* and *q* are *false*.

Answer (score 1):

Logicians like things to be clear and succinct, but the English language was not designed by logicians. It is still being developed as it has been for the last 1000 years by a committee of over 1,000,000,000 people, most of whom have no understanding of logic.
If you want to be clear, you may have to forego a little succinctness and add a couple of words:

1. If Tenant does not achieve *x* and does not achieve *y* then Tenant may terminate the lease.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "neither x nor y" is least ambiguous way to express it concisely.

However, an even clearer way to say it would be to give up on conciseness:

> If Tenant fails to X and also fails to Y, Tenant may terminate the lease.

If you had more than 2 or 3 conditions, you could express them as a list, something like:

> If Tenant fails to achieve *each* of the following conditions, Tenant may terminate the lease:
>
> 1. A
> 2. B
> 3. ...

However, as someone mentioned in the comments, for legal documents your best bet is to consult a lawyer. There's often specific terminology that has become customary. Leases like yours are probably not unique, and there's almost certainly precedent for language that should be used.

Comment: The list version looks ambiguous to me. It could mean "fails to achieve A and fails to achieve B and fails to achieve ..." (as intended) or it could mean "fails to achieve the combination of A, B, ...."

Comment: Could you explain the distinction you're making? I don't see it.

Comment: If the tenant achieves A but fails to achieve B, then it is true that he has failed to achieve the combination but it is false that he has "failed to achieve A and failed to achieve B".

Comment: I see what you're saying. Perhaps it should say "each of the following" instead of "all"?